How to emit on-change event for the e8-form-table-column with a lookup in the column template with Every8.Cloud framework?
I am using Every8.cloud framework. Grid column with lookup.
<e8-form-table
    class="my-3"
    internal-id="tscSalesInvoicesItems"
    v-model="object.tscSalesInvoicesItems"
    :deletion-confirmation="true"
    :label="false"
    on-row-change="onChangeItemRow"
    on-row-add="onAddRow"
    on-row-delete="onChangeRow"
    on-change="onChangeRow">
    <e8-form-table-column
       internal-id="uom"
       width="100px"
       min-width="100px"
       max-width="100px"
       label-horizontal-alignment="center">
    </e8-form-table-column>
</e8-form-table>

In this option onChangeRow event works fine. If I'am using template:
<e8-form-table-column
    internal-id="uom"
    width="100px"
    min-width="100px"
    max-width="100px"
    label-horizontal-alignment="center">
    <template #default="{ row, index }">
        <e8-form-lookup
            v-model="row.uom"
            :lazy-sync="false"
            :label="false"
            source="lstUnitsOfMeasure"
            placeholder="UOM">
        </e8-form-lookup>
    </template>
</e8-form-table-column>

On-change event for lookup doesn't emit onChangeRow event for the <e8-form-table>.
How to emit on-change event for the <e8-form-table> with a value row.uom from <e8-form-lookup>?

Could you please add a minimal-reproducible-example?
